# Taking the Average of a Data Set in Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm in the process of designing an app but coming a bit unstuck with Javascript. So far I have a Firebase Realtime Database with the following structure.[!
[image]

What I'd like to do is for each time an area in green is added / updated, take a value(red) from that area in green get the average from all the values that are held within each green object and place it into a brown object at the bottom.

Would anyone have any idea on how to complete this using Javascript / Firebase functions?

JSON Export:

```
{
  "5Rz8DpU34PeXAcnriD6vEiPu7jk2" : {
    "UiWK7RkdeCbUte8g7naB9qp42qu1" : {
      "rating1" : 5
    },
    "average" : 0
  },
  "Fi43uP2LcbVLi2uFwUyCAp2uvSH2" : {
    "average" : 0
  },
  "UiWK7RkdeCbUte8g7naB9qp42qu1" : {
    "Fi43uP2LcbVLi2uFwUyCAp2uvSH2" : {
      "rating1" : 5,
      "rating2" : 5
    },
    "asdas" : {
      "rating1" : 2
    },
    "average" : 0
  },
  "gov4hRpDgDVhyVgsQrYJnn1rfeW2" : {
    "UiWK7RkdeCbUte8g7naB9qp42qu1" : {
      "rating1" : 5
    },
    "average" : 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Cloud Function code should do the trick:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.database();

exports.average = functions.database
  .ref('/ratings/{blueId}/{greenId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    const blueId = context.params.blueId;
    const blueRef = db.ref('ratings/' + blueId);

    const blueAverageRef = db.ref('ratings/' + blueId + '/average');

    let totalSum = 0;
    let nbrOfElem = 0;

    return blueRef
      .once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          if (childSnapshot.val().val) {
            //console.log(childSnapshot.val());
            totalSum += childSnapshot.val().val;
            nbrOfElem++;
          }
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        //console.log('totalSum: ' + totalSum);
        //console.log('nbrOfElem: ' + nbrOfElem);
        return blueAverageRef.transaction(function(average) {
          if (nbrOfElem > 0) {
            return { val: totalSum / nbrOfElem };
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
```

Note that it uses a Transaction, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction

The database shall be structured as:

```
-ratings
   -blueNode1
      -greenNode11
         -val:2  // <- red node in your picture
      -greenNode12
         -val:10
      -average   // <- red node in your picture
         -val:6
   -blueNode2
      -greenNode21
         -val:5
      -greenNode22
         -val:3
      -greenNode23
         -val:1
      -average
         -val:5
```

Comment: ReferenceError: db is not defined 

?

Comment: I've added to extra lines at the beginning of the code.

Comment: It's running successfully but it's giving me an average of 0? 5 /1 = 5?

Comment: Hmm... works well for me. Create one green node with a sub-node val: 5 and average for the blue parent node is 5.

Comment: I've added to the answer the structure of the database that you nee to use.

Comment: does your answer still work on the first value added? i'm just wondering if it's calc is coming to 0 because it's not reading the first value?

Comment: @JamesPalfrey yes it works perfectly with a brand new value. I added a new blue node and under it one green node and it worked.

Comment: and it updated the brown node from the average of the two red nodes?

Comment: Yes indeed. I have updated my answer with the full database structure, showing how average is displayed. Note that you don't have to create the average nodes, they create automatically. Did you try it in your environment?

Comment: @JamesPalfrey Any news?

Comment: Hey Renaud sorry i've been away on holiday! i'm still getting the same error...the function is running but it's not updating the average. It keeps updating it with 0?

Comment: From the looks of it the error occurs when this area is run:

return blueAverageRef.transaction(function(average) {
          if (nbrOfElem > 0) {
            return { val: totalSum / nbrOfElem };
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        });
      })

Comment: Hi @JamesPalfrey, could you add an export of your database to your post? From the Firebase console, on the Real Time Database section, click the button with three verticla dots and choose Export JSON..

Comment: @JamesPalfrey you should change the node name of ratingX to val, see the code of the answer as well as the example of database structure at the end of the answer. I see that you may have several ratings under one green node: you should sligthly adapt the code to take that into account, since the current version of the code treats only one val node. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd appreciate the same if you thought the question provided everything you needed :)

Comment: Renaud....how would i do this if i had multiple values in val...i.e val1, val 2 etc...each needs to have an average calculated and uploaded to a seperate average1 average 2 etc?

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
exports.detectGreenChanges = functions.database.ref('/requests/{blueId}/{greenId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const greenIdData = change.after.val();
  const blueId = context.params.blueId;
  const greenId = context.params.greenId;

  // Do whatever you want with the data and set it to where ever you want

});
```

Take a look at [this docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), it'll help you set the value back to where you want.

Good luck!